# creating an app that displays the name of the song that is being played in my spotify account

Tags: flutter, dart, spotify

I want to create a basic app which displays the name of the song that is currently being played on my spotify account. I've created an app in my spotify developers portal to get the client id and stuff but i'm unable to figure out how to implement the authentication in my flutter code.

I'm very new to flutter and I'm just stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/spotify_sdk) when unsure of the usage of a package. Specifically to authenticate you can use this function: `await SpotifySdk.connectToSpotifyRemote(clientId: "", redirectUrl: "")`. There is also an [example](https://github.com/brim-borium/spotify_sdk/blob/main/example/lib/main.dart) (Authentication function signature: `Future<void> connectToSpotifyRemote() async`).